# Best practice for maintaining constants in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have an old doubt about constants in Java Projects maintenance. From my perspective, when we try putting the constants inside an Abstract class like that:

```
public final class MyConstants {
public static final String CONSTANT1 = "const1";
public static final String CONSTANT2 = "const2";
public static final String CONSTANT3 = "const3";
public static final String CONSTANT4 = "const4";
}
```

after that using those constants inside classes in the project:

```
public void myMethod(final Map params) {
final String myparam = (String) params.get(MyConstants.CONSTANT1);
//DO SOMETHING WITH PARAMS
}
```

It leads to boiler plate code, verbose use of constants and no real advances. In other hand if we put those constants inside the class for somehow people don't like it. They say "what about we have the same constant declare somewhere?" the problem is maintainance issues, if we change those constants in that class the change can be visible on several parts without any big problem.

Those constants are mainly used for mapping webservices for java perspective without having to generating POJOs like JAXB based on WSDL, the webservices operations are mapped directly for key value maps in Java.
I want to know what do you think about this approach and if we have any other choice.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use raw types. That `Map` should be parameterized.

Comment: A constant (usually) cannot change without being a breaking change. *This is no different than any other API breaking change.* Then the question is just *what* should be a constant and what should be just a literal in code ..

Comment: @DavidConrad are you saying something like that: Map<String, Object> in case its the same problem, we are just putting some generics, the problem of maintaining the keys persists.

Comment: @user2864740 are you saying could be the same result as keeping those constants inside the classes where its needed and if changes some of it just searching entire source code and changing manually?

Comment: @LambdaPool It matters as to *what* these "constants" represent and how they are used; and *what* the implications of changing a value is. XML tags are constants, but using constant/static fields for such usually results in a horrible mess (on the other hand, namespaces can usually make useful constants). Also, configuration items (as pointed out by Elliott) are not "constants" to begin with; even if they can be referred to by constants.

Comment: My comment wasn't addressed at the problem in your question, but just at best practices. Raw types are frowned upon, and if you can make it a `Map<String, String>` you can eliminate the cast. If you use raw types, you will frequently have warnings and will not get the type safety that generics can provide.

Comment: @DavidConrad ok it was just a sample, can be parametrized in practice they are.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your concern, don't hardcode those constants as values *except perhaps as defaults* and store them with [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and/or [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)(s). You might also read the Java Tutorial on [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). Something like,

```
Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("my.proprties");
props.load(in);
String v = props.get("CONSTANT_ONE", "const1"); // <-- the "1" is a default.
```

Then if you need to change the property later you only have to modify the properties file.

Comment: A constant is a contract, just as 0 is 0. Not everything should be a constant, but to make a "constant" from configurable properties is arguably very wrong.

Comment: @user2864740 I was answering the *if we have any other choice*; perhaps OP was giving an example where a constant key is appropriate. However, when translating or localizing things the above is very appropriate as you can modify the translation without making code changes.

Comment: A translatable resource is not a constant. A constant ("CONSTANT_ONE") might refer to the resource.

Comment: @user2864740 *are mainly used for mapping webservices for java perspective* sounds like a configurable `String` to me (and not a constant).

Comment: I'm merely playing the devil's advocate.

Comment: Hi @Elliot Frisch, those constants are references for xml tags IDs, for example: <user><name>ed</name></user> it will be translated for keys user and name, inside the map they are dynamic attributes like the old dynabeans API from Apache.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution of using Properties... maybe for a large project could be efficient somehow. But the problem is how naming those properties keys...

Comment: You choose a naming standard and you stick to it. One common example I see is `something.other.name=Fred`; but it's not really different from naming a variable.